# DefaultView.RowFilter filtro por data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Boa tarde, estou preenchido um GridView, porém quando vou realizar o filtro, me informa o seguinte erro "Referência de objeto não definida para uma instância de um objeto."
O campo que eu estou tentando filtrar, vencimento, é do tipo date, e utilizo SQL.
Já tentei de várias formas, com # entre as datas, configurando, porém sem ocorre o mesmo erro.

Tentei assim:

```html
 ds.Tables["cantas_apagar"].DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, "vencimento >= # {0} #", txtDataInicial.Text) + "and" + String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat, "vencimento <= # {0} #", txtDataInicial.Text);
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Assim:

```html
 ds.Tables["cantas_apagar"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "(vencimento >= #" + txtDataInicial.Text + " # and vencimento <= #" + txtDataFinal.Text + "#)";
                    GridView1.DataBind();
```

Se alguém tiver alguma ideia, agradeço. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema, na verdade não estava nas datas, e sim porque o grid não estava sendo carregado quando ia realizar o filtro, coloquei para carregar antes chamando o método no button de pesquisa, e funcionou perfeitamente.